How do I build an existing react project?
I'm not expirenced in react app development. I got a react project passed down form another developer from on my team and I can't figure out how to build it
What I did:
npm i react
npm install 
npm run build

my build results in an error message:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\react-client\build\2.chunk.js'
BUT the .gitignore file contains the /build directory (as to not occupy too much space on gitlab i presume) so any "build" files are meant to be generated in the build process?
package:
{
  "name": "react-req-for-pay-ui",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "***",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "npm run rm_client & react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "rm_client": "rimraf ../src/main/resources/client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "***",
  "license": "***",
  "dependencies": {
    "@atlaskit/button": "^13.4.2",
    "@atlaskit/datetime-picker": "^9.2.8",
    "@atlaskit/form": "^7.4.1",
    "@atlaskit/icon-priority": "^5.0.2",
    "@atlaskit/modal-dialog": "^11.1.6",
    "@atlaskit/navigation-next": "^8.0.0",
    "@atlaskit/page": "^11.0.14",
    "@atlaskit/radio": "^4.0.6",
    "@atlaskit/textarea": "^2.2.6",
    "@atlaskit/textfield": "^3.1.7",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "16.9.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.1",
    "react-app-rewire-uglifyjs": "0.1.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "2.1.6",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "rimraf": "3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie < 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}


Can you show the package.json file

@DileepaMabulage thanks for responding i updated my post with package contetns thanks

Were there any cache files in the directory you may have to delete before trying to build again? Also, running npm i react may have installed a newer version of React than the previous developer was using. Try reverting any changes, deleting node_modules and installing with npm ci instead.

can you provide the github url for the repository

unfortunately removing node_modules and running npm ci resulted in same error. i cannot share the repo because it is in my company's private gitlab
